# Did Quidditch take place during Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

Not a lot of time is spent focussing on Hogwarts during the seventh book, but I was wondering if there was any evidence of there being any Quidditch taking place during the time the trio were hunting for horcruxes?

There were still the four houses, and the Quidditch pitches were still standing until the Battle of Hogwarts (when they were destroyed by Death Eaters), but it seems unlikely the Death Eaters would want Slytherin to look bad if they lost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Unknown.**

There is no mention of Quidditch in *Deathly Hallows* that might refer to the inter-house Quidditch Cup. I am also unaware of any J.K. Rowling interview which touches upon this point.

---

If I had to guess, I would probably guess that it didn’t take place. We know that Snape is a double agent, trying to keep the students safe from the Carrows:

> [Dumbledore said] “I am counting upon you to remain in Lord Voldemort’s good books as long as possible, or Hogwarts will be left to the mercy of the Carrows….”
>
> — *Deathly Hallows*, chapter 33 (*The Prince’s Tale*)

Quidditch is an immensely dangerous sport, and there’s plenty of scope for an “accident” to occur to somebody on the pitch, whether at the hands of a student or one of the Carrows. He’d be expected to join in the student-baiting, so no counter-courses or spells for him. Then consider that Quidditch players are fairly high-profile students, and come in for a fair amount of flak, and you see why Snape might be reluctant to allow Quidditch games to run.

There are plenty of plausible cover stories:

- The lack of players (because so many students are absent)
- Wanting to stop students having fun
- Restricting access to brooms, to stop students trying to escape the school (a la Fred and George Weasley)
- To avoid any reminders of Harry or any other high-profile Quidditch players who are now part of the rebellion against Voldemort

You can imagine the Carrows would happily go along with several of those.

Comment: That makes sense. Imagine the Carrows would happily Cruciatus anyone who had the audacity of trying to score against Slytherin as well.

Comment: they did attempt to run the school like nothing was happening, technicly you the average person wasnt supposed to know the ministry was being run by puppets, and since the media was being 100% controlled as well the average person may not have known. so to keep up these appearances having school run normally is a must. to make up for the part where wed want slytherins to win, simply making up reasons for x gryffandor players to get suspended from the game would be enough to keep slytherins team winning. (subs are generally bad)

Comment: @Himarm: They run the school as normal, with students practicing the Cruciatus Curse on anybody who’s got a detention, getting kidnapped from the Hogwarts Express, and used as knife-sharpeners when they disagree with the Carrows. I don't think the cancellation of Quidditch would be particularly noteworthy, in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: there were punishments yes, and they filtered out the muggle borns, but in the media the muggle borns were being segregated too, however again your average student had probably an average experiance. if your ginny or neville and you mouth off, your gana get punished, if your random lame hufflepuff number 3, your probably perfectly fine. 
they might have canceled it, leaving the system in tact with minor changes is the best way to take over an organization. even if your minor changes involve killing a whole race of people. (hitler)

Comment: They wanted to abolish all the houses and just have Slytherin, so I guess they would've stopped the Cup in it's inter-house form regardless