# Did Draco go to Hogwarts during the events of Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

Did Draco Malfoy go to Hogwarts during the events of *Deathly Hallows*?

I ask because, although he turned up for the Battle of Hogwarts, he was also at Malfoy Manor in March, which wasn’t holiday time.

Comment: it was easter holidays most likely, aka spring break

Comment: According to [HP Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Draco_Malfoy), "Draco attended his seventh year of Hogwarts that year. During the Easter holidays, Draco was seen at home in Malfoy Manor." I'm searching for a better source.

Comment: I'm not a very experienced user on this site but I was hoping someone could explain why this question has upvotes. One of the criteria for up/down voting is "this question shows/does not show research effort", and this question doesn't seem to show much effort. Mikasa identifies a pretty specific part of the book, and reading this passage would pretty quickly reveal the quote that Himarm found. Doesn't that indicate that there's little research effort put into the question? I want to be fair to Mikasa by understanding the guidelines for voting before downvoting this question.

Comment: @BenSutton technically movie only viewers could miss this, and we also cannot assume they OP owns or has a copy of the book at hand, but yes alot of questions like this do end up getting downvotes, my quick answer actually helps give the question upvotes as well.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Draco did indeed attend Hogwarts in his 7th year, as it was mandatory, by his boss/parents boss Voldemort.

> ‘Follow me,’ said Narcissa, leading the way across the hall. ‘My
>   son, Draco, is home for his Easter holidays. If that is Harry Potter,
>   he will know.’ *-Deathly Hallows*